# Error [sforce-2900000]: INVALID_FIELD: Can select only RecordId, a Has*Access field, and MaxAccessLevel

Tags: apex, soql, api

Running the below query returns and error message

> Error [sforce-2900000]: INVALID_FIELD: Can select only RecordId, a Has*Access field, and MaxAccessLevel

```
SELECT 
    RecordId,
    HasReadAccess,
    HasTransferAccess,
    MaxAccessLevel
FROM UserRecordAccess
WHERE UserId = [Id] AND RecordId = [Id]
```

Where Id is some value.

I copied this query from the UserRecordAccess description page. (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm)

Can someone point if I'm missing something here.

Comment: That exact query works for me :\

Comment: Those fields, despite claiming to take an ID in the docs are actually defined as some sort of super-strange picklist on the backend. Try passing your ID values as strings instead of the ID data type?